# How to create a Java Soundbank programmatically

Tags: java, midi, javasound

I want to create a small soundbank programmatically with my own samples and play them through the standard Sun JDK Midi Synthesizer.

A already read they are in Beatnik format, but I can't find the spec.

In addition, I don't really need the soundbank stored as a file, since it would be OK if there was a way to create a soundbank from samples programmatically prior using the bank to play the instruments in it.

Any ideas?

UPDATE 21.01.2021: Since Java 7 sf2-soundbanks are supported! So just stop thinking abount that beatnik stuff, the company is gone anyway. Here is the spec: http://www.synthfont.com/sfspec24.pdf

Comment: Have you seen [`MidiSystem.getSoundbank(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiSystem.html#getSoundbank%28java.io.File%29) (also overloaded to work with `URL` and `InputStream`)?

Comment: Of course. But I want to know what the file has to contain.

Comment: Oh right, sorry.  Don't know.

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: No, I skipped that because I didn't find any open-source or at least free software that could create soundbanks which would make me able to reverse engineer the stuff...

Comment: Oh, and since Java 7 sf2-soundbanks are supported! So just stop thinking abount that beatnik stuff, the company is gone anyway.

Comment: It's still there (in the module java.desktop), also in the newest versions of JDK. Have you seen Sun/Oracle's documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-synth.html ?

Comment: @greenmarker Soundbanks are still there, yes, but now they are provided in SF2 Format and not Beatnik anymore (afaik). Or did I miss something?